# 500 error when deploying django-testapp to app-engine using django-nonrel

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm trying to get up and running with the django-testapp on app
engine.  I've gotten it working fine in my development environment,
but I'm getting 500 server errors when I deploy it to app engine.

Here's what I'm doing:

Per http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/01/Native-Django-on-App-Engine#disqus_thread

```
   hg clone http://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangoappengine/
   hg clone http://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-testapp/
   hg clone http://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-nonrel/
   cd django-testapp/common-apps
   ln -s ../../djangoappengine
   ln -s ../../django-nonrel/django
```

Then editing app.yaml to change the app id, and converting index.yaml
to unix line endings as per
http://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational/browse_thread/thread/435af89b8ceb60dc/36769ee4cff2c337?lnk=gst&q=index.yaml#36769ee4cff2c337

Then I used "python2.5 manage.py runserver" (as per
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1446) and
got the "It worked!" page.

Then I did "python2.5 manage.py deploy".  Here's my most recent output
from running this command:

```
Application: xxx; version: 1.
Server: appengine.google.com.
Scanning files on local disk.
Scanned 500 files.
Scanned 1000 files.
Initiating update.
Cloning 75 static files.
Cloning 1190 application files.
Cloned 100 files.
Cloned 200 files.
Cloned 300 files.
Cloned 400 files.
Cloned 500 files.
Cloned 600 files.
Cloned 700 files.
Cloned 800 files.
Cloned 900 files.
Cloned 1000 files.
Cloned 1100 files.
Deploying new version.
Checking if new version is ready to serve.
Will check again in 1 seconds.
Checking if new version is ready to serve.
Will check again in 2 seconds.
Checking if new version is ready to serve.
Will check again in 4 seconds.
Checking if new version is ready to serve.
Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
Uploading index definitions.
Uploading cron entries.
2010-02-20 19:32:52,527 WARNING datastore_file_stub.py:623 Could not
read datastore data from /var/folders/VO/VO12Voe8HAm0b5OtzkzBmk+++TQ/-
Tmp-/django_xxx.datastore
Running syncdb.
```

But when I try to visit the app url, I get a bunch of 500 errors:

```
02-20 05:33PM 23.710 / 500 992ms 1466cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0
(Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML,
like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.307.9 Safari/532.9,gzip(gfe)
75.211.119.241 - - [20/Feb/2010:17:33:24 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0
- "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; en-US)
AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.307.9 Safari/
532.9,gzip(gfe)" "xxx.appspot.com"
E 02-20 05:33PM 24.692
Exception in request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in get_response
   return callback(request, **param_dict)
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/views/defaults.py", line 13, in page_not_found
   t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a
404.html template.
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/template/loader.py", line 144, in get_template
   template, origin = find_template(template_name)
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/template/loader.py", line 125, in find_template
   raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 404.html
E 02-20 05:33PM 24.697
<class 'django.template.TemplateDoesNotExist'>: 500.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
djangoappengine/main/main.py", line 86, in <module>
   main()
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
djangoappengine/main/main.py", line 45, in real_main
   util.run_wsgi_app(application)
 File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/
util.py", line 97, in run_wsgi_app
   run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
 File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/
util.py", line 115, in run_bare_wsgi_app
   result = application(env, _start_response)
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
   response = self.get_response(request)
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/core/handlers/base.py", line 131, in get_response
   return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver,
sys.exc_info())
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in handle_uncaught_exception
   return callback(request, **param_dict)
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/views/defaults.py", line 23, in server_error
   t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a
500.html template.
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/template/loader.py", line 144, in get_template
   template, origin = find_template(template_name)
 File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/1.340031474735303921/common-apps/
django/template/loader.py", line 125, in find_template
   raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
```

I'm using App Engine 1.3.1.654 on (GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app on Mac
OS X 10.6.2) and django-testapp 45:9d23e5b235cf (dated Thurs Feb 18),
django-nonrel 1fbce9199a32, and djangoappengine 3a45a7f6ee87.

Am I missing a step anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be just one of expectations.  If I create a simple application using startapp and wire it up according to the django 1.1 instructions, when I deploy it to app-engine everything works fine.

So the 500 server error was actually just a red herring.